# random safari crashes while using requirejs with fullpage.js and scrollmagic

Tags: javascript, safari, requirejs, fullpage.js, scrollmagic

I’m trying to get a website working with requirejs, based on the use-init boilerplate. It works fine in most systems and in most of the browsers. But it fails (combined with ‘scrollmagic’, ‘fullpage.js’ and other script) in safari on random system versions (iMac, MBP) and random Safari versions (occurred in Safari 6, 7 and 8). In this case the browser just showed a couple of elements, struggled while scrolling and crashed after time.

**update:** It works for tested devices in uncompressed, but not in the build version (r.js)

While I don’t know the reason for this behavior, I try to catch every mistake. I don’t know if the wrong behavior results from my lack of knowledge, if I do something completely wrong or if there is a bug inside one of the used tools. So I want to ask you – do you have any hints for me?

I’m not sure about the right implementation of plugins in requirejs. I think I got the right use for ‘scrollmagic’, but I’m not sure about ‘fullpage.js’. Is it possible to write a module-like use of ‘fullpage.js’ or is the use right as per particulars given below? Already studied the documentations, since I use all the stuff the first time, I would appreciate any help!

Best regards
Jakob
—
http://jakob.grommas.com/bt/
http://jakob.grommas.com/bt-raw/

In case of doing something wrong, here a detailed strip down for config, main and modules.

config.js :

```js
require.config({
    deps: ['plugins/console', 'main'],
    paths: {
        domReady: '../components/domReady/domReady',
        TweenMax:  '../components/ScrollMagic/js/_dependent/greensock/TweenMax.min',
        TweenLite: '../components/ScrollMagic/js/_dependent/greensock/TweenLite.min',
        TimelineMax: '../components/ScrollMagic/js/_dependent/greensock/TimelineMax.min',
        jquery: '../components/jquery/dist/jquery.min',
        fullPage: '../components/fullpage.js/jquery.fullPage.min',
        scrollMagic: '../components/ScrollMagic/js/jquery.scrollmagic',
        lazySizes: '../components/lazysizes/lazysizes.min',
        viewportUnits: '../components/viewport-units-buggyfill/viewport-units-buggyfill'
    },

    shim: {
        'fullPage': ['jquery'],
        'scrollMagic': ['jquery', 'TweenMax'],
        'TweenMax': {
            deps: ['jquery'],
            exports: 'TweenMax'
        }
    },
    // Prevent caching issues, by adding an additional URL argument
    urlArgs: 'bust=' + (new Date()).getDate()

});
```

main.js :

```js
require(['lazySizes']);
require(['viewportUnits']);
require(['modules/fullpage']);
require(['domReady', 'modules/scrollmagic.controller', 'modules/scrollmagic.scene'], function(domReady, Controller, Scenes) {
    'use strict';
    domReady(function () {
        Controller.getController().addScene([
            Scenes.getScene00(),
            Scenes.getScene01()
            //...
        ]);
    });
});
```

modules/fullpage.js :

```js
define([
    //  Dependencies of the module
    'domReady',
    'jquery',
    'fullPage'
], function (domReady, $) {
    //  Strict mode to prevent sloppy JS
    'use strict';
    domReady(function () {
    //  This function is called once the DOM is ready.
    //  It will be safe to query the DOM and manipulate
    //  DOM nodes in this function.
        var indexAll = {},
            getSectionIndex = $('section').length,
            currentSlide;

        $("#viewport").fullpage({
            sectionSelector: 'section',
            slideSelector: 'article',
            menu: '#menu',
            anchors: ['example1', 'example2', 'example3'],
            autoScrolling: false,
            keyboardScrolling: true,
            continuousVertical: true,
            loopHorizontal: true,
            scrollingSpeed: 800,
            verticalCentered: false,
            easing: 'easeInQuart',
            css3: false,
            fixedElements: '.pinContainer',
            slidesNavigation: false,
            afterRender: function(){
                    // do nothing
            },
            afterLoad: function(anchorLink, index){
                currentSlide = indexAll[index];
                if (index === 1) {
                    // do this
                } else {
                    // do that
                }
                if (index > 2 && index < getSectionIndex - 1) {
                    // do this
                    if (index === 3 || index === getSectionIndex - 2) {
                        // do this
                    } else {
                        // do that
                    }
                } else {
                    // do that
                }
                var ignoreThisShit = anchorLink;    // DIRTY HACK
                ignoreThisShit = 'ignoreThisShit';  // DIRTY HACK
            },
            afterSlideLoad: function(anchorLink, index, slideAnchor, slideIndex){
                var currentSlideIndex = slideIndex + 1;
                indexAll[index] = currentSlideIndex;
                if (index > 3 < getSectionIndex - 3) {
                    // do this
                } else {
                    // do that
                }
                var ignoreThisShit = anchorLink;    // DIRTY HACK
                ignoreThisShit = slideAnchor;       // DIRTY HACK
                ignoreThisShit = 'ignoreThisShit';  // DIRTY HACK
            }
        });
    });
});
```

modules/scrollmagic.controller.js :

```js
define([
    // Dependencies of the module
    'jquery',
    'scrollMagic'
], function ($, ScrollMagic) {
    // Strict mode to prevent sloppy JS
    'use strict';
    // Private variables
    var _controller = new ScrollMagic.Controller();
    // Public API
    return {
        // Getter for private variable
        getController: function () {
            return _controller;
        },
        // File an event on initialisation
        init: function () {
            $(document).trigger(_controller);
        }
    };
});
```

modules/scrollmagic.scene.js :

```js
define([
    // Dependencies of the module
    'jquery',
    'TweenMax',
    'scrollMagic'
], function ($, TweenMax, ScrollMagic) {
    // Strict mode to prevent sloppy JS
    'use strict';
    // private functions
    var windowHeight  = $(window).innerHeight();
    function getWindowHeight() {
        return windowHeight;
    }
    // Private variables
    var _scene01 = new ScrollMagic.Scene({
        triggerElement: '#section1',
        triggerHook: 0,
        duration: getWindowHeight
    }).setPin($('#pinContent2'));
    var _scene02 = new ScrollMagic.Scene({
        triggerElement: '#section2',
        triggerHook: 1,
        duration: getWindowHeight
    }).setTween(TweenMax.to('#section1', 1, {backgroundColor: '#000'}));
    // Public API
    return {
        // Getter for private variable
        getScene01: function () {
            return _scene01;
        },
        getScene02: function () {
            return _scene02;
        },
        // File an event on initialisation
        init: function () {
            $(document).trigger(_scene01).trigger(_scene02); // is this right?
        }   
    };
});
```